# Is their any fullfledged PaaS providing from Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, paas, iaas

Is there any **PaaS** providing from Amazon like **Heroku ,  Pivotal Cloud Foundry, IBM Bluemix**?

I know that they have many PaaS helpful services like **Amazon RDS** for database as a service, **Amazon elastic Beanstalk** etc which makes blur line between IaaS and Paas concept. but at the end of the day we need to orchestrate all of these thing together. So is there any orchestration providing available from AWS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the challenges in AWS is that its difficult to draw the line between SaaS, PaaS and IaaS, since there are large number of services available with different functionalities.

However, you can consider AWS Elastic Beanstalk as a PaaS which allows you to provision Web and Database Servers without deeply knowing the underling IaaS aspects of AWS (Though it provisions EC2 instances, Elastic Load Balancers and Autoscaling Groups behind the scene).

If you are planning on using Docker Orchestration, you can consider using AWS ECS as an alternative to docker Swarm.

In addition, there is the AWS Serverless Stack (API Gateway, Lambda) which also can be used to develop applications which is fully managed by AWS.